# JavaScript doesn't run after recreating the activity with the webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a local html file on the sdcard, which I load into a webview. The html has two buttons, the first button one displays some text on the webview, and the second button clears the text on the webview.
When the webview is run for the first time, this works fine. But when I leave the activity with the webview, and then recreate the same activity later on, the first button doesn't work anymore.

I have use these setup for the webview

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///_path_to_file_on_sdcard_");
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

The html:

```
<p>JSONP Example</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
          $("#button1").click(function(){
        try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            async: false,
            url: "http://myserver.com/json.php?iamback=?",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback:"flightHandler",
            success: function(data){
                $("#content").html('');
                $("#content").append('Your data is' + data+'.<br />');                  $("#content").append('Your name is' + data.name+'.<br />');                 $("#content").append('You live in' + data.addr+'.');         
                },
            error: function(){
                alert('fail');
                }
            });
                     }
        catch(err)
        {
            alert(err);
        }
        }); 

        $("#button2").click(function(){
            a$("#content").html('');
        });
        });
<p><button id="button1">JSONP Example</button> <br /> <br /> 
   <button id="button2">Clear</button> </p>
<div id="content">testing abc</div>
```

The URL http://myserver.com/json.php?iamback=? returns this:

```
?({'name' : 'Tom','addr':'Taipei'})
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here?
Anyone has any ideas or keywords I can use to find some answers? 
Thanks!

Comment: just in case if webview caching content add this -  webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false); And make sure to set null webview ondestory and reload/ini it oncreate.

Comment: Thanks Neha. I already did webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false) on init, and also webView.clearCache(true) in onDestroy.
p.s.- In my app, I create lots of new activities (one at a time) which consists of a webview, and javscript works for the first activity, but doesn't work for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Please try calling `loadUrl` last, after you have set the settings on the WebView.

Comment: Thanks ksasq, actually I do call loadUrl last ---
I've extended the WebView, and call setJavaScriptEnabled in the constuctor of WebView.

Comment: CAn you share any more detail about what you mean by "doesn't work"? Does your app interact with the WebView in any other way other than loading this file?

Comment: I've found my error, I found out I had been calling 
webview.pauseTimers(); in onPause() of my activity, but webview.resumeTimers(); doesn't get called ever in my app. So once I got fixed this, the javascript works perfectly :)

Comment: Yup, that will do it :)